# mpmovieplayercontroller view on uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to play video on uitableviewcell. but click to player view restart video. i want to click video player view open the control menu and click to uitableviewcell restart video.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (self.videoPlayer && [self.indexPath_k isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.imageView.image = [cell.imageView.image Resim_Skala:CGSizeMake(150, 100)];

        UIView *vieww = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 100)];
        self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 100);
        self.videoPlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [vieww addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:vieww];
   }else{

    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
           .....
           [self.videoPlayer play];
            [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Screenshot:

http://postimage.org/image/hafzjkjix/

Comment: Dec 2013 .. TIP - it is hugely flakey about file name extensions (files form the net). In my app, .MOV works, .mov crashes the iPhone hard.  Bizarre.  Also the simulator simply doesn't work, it's totally useless and just crashes.  Finally on the MPMoviePlayerViewController approach works, MPMoviePlayerController is useless and broken.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not the video in the above screenshot that you mentioned. **It is actually a thumbnail image of that video with a play button**. Whenever you click that cell, the video will open in a new view.

{ .. totally wrong: Video playing in tableview cell is not supported by apple by default. }

Otherwise you have to create custom view with that functionality.

Thank You

Comment: "Video playing in tableview cell is not supported by apple by default" if i playing video in tableview cell, does apple approve the program?

Comment: @Akhil: Please provide the reference URL where apple had stated that Apple doesn't support Video Playing in TableviewCell..

Comment: it's completely commonplace to have videos playing in a cell